# how I can split a column of a pyspark dataframe with different size of whitspace?

Tags: pyspark

how I can split a column of a pyspark dataframe with whitspace? The point is that the whitespace can be one, two or more!

For example :

```
col1      
'this is summer'  
'cool      wheather'
'game   over'


col1                          new
'this is summer'           ['this','is','summner']
'cool      wheather'       ['cool', 'wheather']
'game   over'              ['game','over']
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
df3=df3.withColumn('new', F.split('col1','\s+'))
```

Comment: Try: `df3 = df3.withColumn('new', F.split('col1', '\\s+'))`

Comment: df3.show(10, False). what's ur output and error?

Comment: `'\s+'` seems to work fine.

Comment: @samkart It gives me `' '` as an element of the list. specially when the space is in the beginning or at the end of the word.

Comment: do you mean trailing spaces within `col1`? you can get rid of that using `trim`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regex` paramter in [split function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split) is a string representing a regular expression. The regex string should be a `Java regular expression`. In Java, the regular expression needs `two backslashes` to be parsed as escapes in other languages.

```
df3 = df3.withColumn('new', F.split(F.trim('col1'), '\\s+'))
```

Comment: It gives me `' '` as an element but I don't want to have empty string

Comment: It could be leading or trailing whitespace characters, I have updated the answer.